# Solve the inequality 1/x > x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am trying to solve this inequality but I am repeatedly getting an incorrect answer. So I first set the restriction $x$ cannot be $0$ and then split it into two cases. One where $x > 0$ and another where $x < 0$.

When $x$ is above $0$, I  get $1 > x^2\implies -1 < x$ and $ x < 1$. But $x < -1$ is not valid in this case as it has been declared that $x$ is above $0$ in this case so you get $0 < x < 1$ which is correct.

The other case is when $x$ is below $0$ so I must flip the sign because I am multiplying by $x$ when it is negative. I get $1 < x^2$, $1 < x$,$-1 < x$. This is incorrect because the domain must be that $x < -1$, I understand why my answer is wrong logically but I do not know where I made the mistake in my work.

Here is picture of my work:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2FAm.png)

Comment: If $x<0$, then $x^2>1$ doesn't imply $x>±1$. This implies $ |x|=-x>1\implies x<-1$...That was a your mistake..

Comment: Remember, $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, not $x$.

Comment: What I'm surprised is that no answer to the OP's exact question "where l made the mistake" exact answer... It would be better to have this in an answer than a comment...

Comment: If you're given $a < b$ then if you add $-a-b$ to both sides you get $-b<-a$. This is where the rule comes from that multiplying by negatives reverses the direction of the inequality. However, in practice, I find doing the addition is less prone to errors than reasoning about the multiplication. I believe this is one of those cases.

Comment: @nonstudent I didn't give an explanation since it was already given here. But I think your are right and I've just added it now. Thanks

Comment: How did you get $-1 < x$ in your $x < 0$ case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you are given that $\frac{1}{x}>x$ you know that $x\ne0$ since you cannot divide by $0$.

Since multiplication of an inequality by a negative quantity reverses the direction of the inequality, one might instead multiply by $x^2$ rather than by $x$. This gives

\begin{eqnarray} x&>&x^3\\
x-x^3&>&0\\
x(1-x^2)&>&0\\
x(1-x)(1+x)&>&0
\end{eqnarray}
The expression will be non-zero in each of the four intervals $(-\infty,-1),(-1,0),(0,1), (1,\infty)$ but will be positive in only the intervals $(-\infty,-1)$ and $(0,1)$. So the solution of the inequality is

$$ x<-1\quad\text{or}\quad0<x<1 $$

Answer (score 8):

Another way

$$\frac1x>x \iff \frac1x-x>0\iff \frac{1-x^2}{x}>0$$

then

- for $x>0$ we need

$$1-x^2>0 \iff x^2<1 \iff -1<x<1$$

that is

$$0< x<1$$

- for $x<0$ we need

$$1-x^2<0 \iff x^2>1 \iff x<-1 \lor x>1$$

that is

$$x<-1$$

and then

$$x\in (-\infty,-1)\cup(0, 1)$$

Here is a [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2Fx%3Ex) to visualize the solution

[image]

---

As noticed in the comments your mistake is that for $x<0$ isn’t true that

$$1<x^2\implies 1<x \lor -1<x$$

since $\sqrt {x^2}=|x|$ which leads to

$$1<x^2\implies 1<|x|\implies 1<-x\implies x<-1$$

Comment: @nonstudent Yes exactly, it is an equivalent problem.

Answer (score 4):

For $\;x>0\;$:

$$\frac1x>x\implies x^2<1\implies |x|<1\implies 0<x<1$$

For $\;x<0\;$ :

$$\frac1x>x\implies x^2>1\implies|x|>1\implies x<-1$$

Comment: |x|>1⟹x<−1
Why does the inequality sign get flipped here?

Comment: @CrispyNuggets Because that's the meaning of that inequality with absolute value: $$\;|x|>1\iff x<-1\;\;or\;\;x>1\;$$ and since we were working with $\;x<0\;$ then we're done.

Comment: More explicitly, resolve $|x|>1$ for $x<0$ to $-x>1$ and thus $x<-1$.

Answer (score -2):

Given that

$0 < x < \dfrac{1}{x}, \;\; (1)$

we may multiply through by $x$ and find

$0 < x^2 < 1; \;\; (2)$

this in turn implies

$x < 1,  \;\; (3)$

since

$x \ge 1 \;\; (4)$

immediately yields

$x^2 \ge 1, \;\; (5)$

in contradiction to (2).  Combining (1) and (3) yields

$0 < x < 1, \;\; (6)$

and dividing this through by $x > 0$ we obtain

$0 < 1 < \dfrac{1}{x}; \;\; (7)$

(6) and (7) together beget

$0 < x < \dfrac{1}{x}. \;\; (8)$

We have now shown that every $x$ satisfying (1) lies in the interval $(0, 1)$; that is,  $(0, 1)$ contains all positive solutions to

$x < \dfrac{1}{x}, \;\; (9)$

and that every $x \in (0, 1)$ satisfies (9).

Now suppose (9) holds with

$x < 0; \;\; (10)$

then since

$x < 0 \Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{1}{x} < 0, \;\; (11)$

we can assume that

$x < \dfrac{1}{x} < 0. \;\; (12)$

We multiply (12) through by $x < 0$, and obtain

$x^2 > 1 > 0, \;\; (13)$

which together with $x < 0$ forces

$x < -1 < 0; \;\;(14)$

thus every solution of (12) obeys (14).  Now if $x$ satisfies (14), dividing through by $-x$ gives

$-1 < \dfrac{1}{x} < 0; \;\; (15)$

then combining (14) and (15) we have

$x < \dfrac{1}{x} < 0, \;\; (16)$

in agreenent with (12), and we are done.

It will be noted that the complete set of solutions $X$ to

$x < \dfrac{1}{x} \;\; (17)$

is the union of two disjoint open intervals:

$X = (-\infty, -1) \cup (0, 1); \;\; (18)$

furthermore, the map

$\theta(y) = -\dfrac{1}{y}   \;\; (19)$

is easily seen to carry $(0, 1)$ onto $(-\infty, -1)$ and *vice-versa*; it is also obviously injective.  We apply $\theta$ to (17):

$\theta(x) = -\dfrac{1}{x},  \;\; (20)$

$\theta \left(\dfrac{1}{x} \right) = -x;  \;\; (21)$

then (17) may be written

$-\theta \left(\dfrac{1}{x} \right) < -\theta(x), \;\; (22)$

and multiplying this by $-1$ we obtain

$\theta(x) < \theta \left(\dfrac{1}{x} \right), \;\; (23)$

which shows that the relation expressed by (17) is invariant under the action of $\theta$.